# Negative dimension and module keras.backend has no attribute common errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am just having the following error whilst training a MNIST model(a CNN) using Keras. Complete beginner at machine learning BTW, so apologies if it is something obvious. Any help appreciated

```
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
K.common.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
```

Leads to error module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'common'. When replacing with image_data_format it still does not fix any errors

```
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 3
np.random.seed(seed)

# load data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, 28, 28).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, 28, 28).astype('float32')

print (X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print (X_test.shape, y_test.shape)

# normalize inputs
X_train = X_train / 255
X_test = X_test / 255

# one hot encoding
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
num_op = y_test.shape[1]

print (num_op)

def cnn_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5, 5, padding='valid', input_shape=(1, 28, 28), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_op, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile Model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# Build the model
model = cnn_model()

# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=200, verbose=2)
```

And this leads to error ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 1 for '{{node conv2d_9/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 5, 5, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](conv2d_9_input, conv2d_9/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,1,28,28], [5,5,28,32].

I am just losing my sight on what keeps on going wrong every time I try to fix something, that I might be missing out on something obvious or might have made a mistake or two whilst trying to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the channels *after* and not before height and width.

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
```

Even better:

```
X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=-1)
```